# How to manage Index name while upgrading from neo4j 1.9.x to 2.x?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I encounter a problem doing the migration from *spring-neo4j 2.3.2.RELEASE* to *3.1.0.RELEASE* (neo4j was *1.9.6* and is migrate to *2.0.3*).I had @Index fields in several java classes with an indexName property like this :

```
@Indexed(indexName = "elt_index")
protected String uuid;
```

I did cypher requests like the following which worked very well, but as it seems that it's not allowed anymore to have an indexName, I can't find the good way to do a cypher request starting from my index. Here is the cypher request which worked well :

```
START element=node:elt_index(uuid={uuid}) RETURN element
```

I achieve to write the following query but I'm not sure that it use the index correctly :

```
MATCH (element:Element) WHERE element.uuid={uuid} RETURN element
```

Is it the good way to write such a cypher query in neo4j 2.x ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, that uses the index automatically. If your class is named "Element".